# Change Visual Studio integrated web browser to something else than IE?

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2022, surprisingly, the integrated web browser used is still IE which, as you know, doesn't render most web sites at all.

For instance, when browsing https://learn.microsoft.com you get the following:

[image]

[image]

Looking at Tools, Options menu item and searching for *browser* doesn't yield any result.

**Question:**

How to force Visual Studio to use another browser than IE for its integrated web browser?

Comment: I wonder how you opened that page in VS. There is no place under View menu to open such a browser.

Comment: @LexLi https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.PeekHelp

Comment: It is an open source project which still uses the legacy `WebBrowser` control https://github.com/microsoft/VS-PPT/blob/ee92b43da16d78a1f0e7b117f5a8c24a1704d581/src/PeekF1/src/Peek/F1PeekResultPresentation.cs#L54 so no doubt IE core is used. https://github.com/microsoft/VS-PPT/issues/258 Already a known issue, just nobody fixes it yet.

Comment: You know what, I actually struggled to reproduce it! I remember that the web browser used to be opened as a tab from whatever Microsoft wizard but I couldn't remember which one exactly. I then remembered that this extension was one way to show it. It appears that they entirely ditched that internal web browser in 2022, any of the 'show XYZ help' invariably opens user's browser now.